# Declare 2-dimensional array without knowing the size

Tags: arrays, string, vba, multidimensional-array

**Situation :**

I have an 2-dimensional array called arrayPartNo which has for size of its 2 dimensions (1,X). Each of the X records it contains in its 2nd dimension are strings which contain either 0, 7 , 15 , 23 etc (so +8) characters.

To make it easier to understand, it contains an unknown number of Part Numbers which each have a length of 7 characters. I there are multiple Part Numbers, they are separated with a semicolon (reason for + 8 and not +7).

**Goal :**

Create an other 2-dimensional array called GoodArray which has for the size of the first dimension X (same value as above) and in the second dimension I would like to store each Parts Number separately.

So as an example, if the record Y of arrayPartNo contains 3 Part Numbers (so it's length will be 3*7 + 2*1 = 23), I would like to store those 3 values in GoodArray(Y,0) GoodArray(Y,1) and GoodArray(Y,2).

This is what I did in the code below but the dynamic declaration of GoodArray creates an issue at the start of the Do While Loop.

**Issues :**

1. Size must be a constant if set, so me trying to figure out the size of its first and second dimension (which I did by counting the longest string and deducting the number of Part Number) before declaring it was useless.
2. Any ideas on how to fix that issue ?

   ```
     'Dim arrayPartNo() As Variant

     '... : Part where I store values in the arrayPartNo 

     Dim NumberOfPartNo As Integer ' Number of PartNo in a specific row
     Dim length As Integer ' length of a correct PartNo
     Dim GoodArray() As Variant

       For i = 0 To UBound(arrayPartNo, 2)
       length = 7
       NumberOfPartNo = 0  

       Do
          GoodArray(i, NumberOfPartNo) = Mid(arrayPartNo(0, i), length + 1 - 7, 7)
          NumberOfPartNo = NumberOfPartNo + 1
          length = length + 8
          Debug.Print GoodArray(i, NumberOfPartNo)
       Loop While Len(arrayPartNo(0, i)) >= length
       Next i
   ```

Comment: I think your question would be easier to understand if you include some sample data showing how the two arrays are set up.

Comment: Hey Tim, actually the arrayPartNo was made by taking each records in a field from an Access database (pretty messy I won't hide you). So just to show you the way it was populated : `If Not rs.EOF Then
        arrayPartNo = rs.GetRows
    End If `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

I basically found a way to apply the `Redim Preserve` method which I was not really familiar with.

The following code works :

```
'1) First part, I calculate the size of the 2nd dimension of GoodArray() (which I will declare later), this size is the biggest number of PartNo contained in a record of arrayPartNo

Dim h As Integer
Dim longest As Integer
longest = 0
For h = 0 To UBound(arrayPartNo, 2)
    If Len(arrayPartNo(0, h)) > longest Then longest = Len(arrayPartNo(0, h))
Next h
'MsgBox longest '63 in my case
h = (longest + 1) / 8 ' since h was only used in the loop above we reuse it to store this = 8 in my case -> size of the 2nd dimension
longest = UBound(arrayPartNo, 2) ' same here, we just reuse the variable to store this -> size of the 1st dimension (588 in my case)



Dim NumberOfPartNo As Integer ' Number of PartNo in a specific row
Dim length As Integer ' length of a correct PartNo
Dim GoodArray() As Variant        
ReDim Preserve GoodArray(longest, h)
For i = 0 To UBound(arrayPartNo, 2)
    length = 7
    NumberOfPartNo = 0
    If Len(arrayPartNo(0, i)) > 0 Then
            Do
                GoodArray(i, NumberOfPartNo) = Mid(arrayPartNo(0, i), length + 1 - 7, 7)
                Debug.Print GoodArray(i, NumberOfPartNo) & " " & i
                NumberOfPartNo = NumberOfPartNo + 1
                length = length + 8

            Loop While Len(arrayPartNo(0, i)) >= length
     End If

Next i
```